# Asynchronous HttpWebRequest not functioning

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have this code which is meant to make a async call but it is not, please have a look at it and let me know where is it going wrong.

```
try
{
    byte[] bytes;
    Stream objRequestStream = null;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetJSONforGetMenuDetails(Id, MenuIds));
    wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://" + MobileWLCUrl + urlCreateCacheAPI));
    wReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    wReq.ContentType = "text/x-json";
    wReq.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    wReq.Method = "POST";
    objRequestStream = wReq.GetRequestStream();
    objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    objRequestStream.Close();
    wReq.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
    //resp = WebAccess.GetWebClient().UploadString("http://" + MobileWLCUrl + urlCreateCacheAPI, GetJSONforGetMenuDetails(Id, MenuIds));
    //EngineException.CreateLog("Cache Created (for Menus: " + MenuIds + ") in API for LocationId: " + Id);
}
catch (Exception ex) { EngineException.HandleException(ex); }

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    WebResponse wResp = wReq.EndGetResponse(result) as WebResponse;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
    String res = sr.ReadToEnd();
    EngineException.CreateLog("Cache Created (for Menus: " + MenuIds + ") in API for LocationId: " + LocId);
}
```

Where is it going wrong? When I debug it, it waits for the call to get over to continue, but that should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

[`BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse) is documented to include a synchronous portion:

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to
>   complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection,
>   for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a result,
>   this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread
>   because it might take some time, typically several seconds. In some
>   environments where the webproxy scripts are not configured properly,
>   this can take 60 seconds or more.

Apart from that, if you call `FinishWebRequest` (technically, if you call `EndGetResponse`) *before* the request has had time to complete, `EndGetResponse` will block.

This is expected, since `EndGetResponse` is *required* to return to you an object that you can get the response data from -- but how can it return such an object if the request has not yet completed?